# Send multi channel funnel funnel-reports as email?

Tags: google-analytics

I intend to use Google Analytics multi-channel-funnels for keeping track of affiliates sending traffic to our site. I wish to send the affiliates an e-mail every week showing how many conversions they contributed to.

Most reports in Google Analytics supports this but not the multi-channel-funnels. Why not and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 1):

You can pull the data using the Multi-Channel Funnels Reporting API

The API allows you to query for metrics like Assisted Conversions, First Interactions Conversions, and Last Interaction conversions, as well as Top Paths, Path Length and Time Lag, to incorporate conversion path data into your applications.

Source: http://blog.programmableweb.com/2012/08/02/google-releases-multi-channel-funnels-reporting-api/

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gdata-migration-guide

Comment: I've been looking through some of that but can't seem to find any sample or request that show what I am looking for. Could you point me to it?